# How to bring a chosen array key to the top of the array?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array as follows:

```
$food['fruit'] = array('apples','oranges','bananas');
$food['veg'] = array('potatoes','onions','peppers');
$food['meat'] = array('bacon','beef','chicken');
```

How would I go about ordering it such that any given type of food would be brought to the top of the array and the rest of the order remains intact?

So if the user selected 'veg' it'd change the order to:

```
$food = array('veg' => ..., 'fruit' => ..., 'meat' => ...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array, rearrange and replace old one:

```
$first = 'veg';

$tmp = array ($first => $food[$first]);
foreach ($food AS $key => $val) {
    if ($key != $first) {
        $tmp[$key] = $val;
    }
}

$food = $tmp;
```

or

```
$first = 'veg';

$tmp = array ($first => $food[$first]);
unset ($food[$first]);
$food = array_merge ($tmp, $food);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. save this entry in tmp_val  : `$tmp_val = array('key'=>$food['key']);`
2. unset this entry from array : `unset($food['key']);`
3. then use [array_unshift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) to insert to the begining :   `array_unshift($food,$tmp_val)`

Comment: array_unshift will insert $tmp_val as first element of $food array. What bcmcfc wants to do is change first key of assoc array.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
$food = array_merge(array('veg' => $food['veg']), $food);
```

but the whole thing looks suspicious to me. Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "the whole thing looks suspicious"? And why do people tend to question the mere existance of questions on this site?

Comment: I see. I took it in the more literal sense (i.e. suspicious of what?) having never previously considered potentially poorly designed code as being "suspicious"!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a sort, since you only want to move one element, so:

- Use [`array_splice()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)to remove the element from the middle of the array.
- Then use [`array_unshift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to add it to the front of the array.

Comment: I think you can't add element to the assoc array using array_unshift as you can only pass a value, without a key.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the loop:

```
$food['fruit'] = array('apples','oranges','bananas');
$food['veg'] = array('potatoes','onions','peppers');
$food['meat'] = array('bacon','beef','chicken');
$food['fish'] = array('code','haddock','plaice');

$key = 'veg';
if (array_key_exists($key,$food)) {
    $tmp[$key] = $food[$key];
    array_splice($food,array_search($key,array_keys($food)),1);
    $food = $tmp+$food;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($food);
echo '</pre>';
```